# Insert calculated value into column without overwriting key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming I have an orderline table with keys (order, orderline) that have restrictions on them preventing someone from updating them, I need to update a calculated column without updating the keys.

```
INSERT INTO ORDERLINES (ORDER, ORDERLINE, CALCULATED)
    SELECT ORDER, ORDERLINE, ORDQTY * PRICE - RECQTY
    FROM ORDERLINES
```

An order can have multiple lines on it, and so calculated has to be a per line calculation, but as far as I can tell, this statement attempts to update order and orderline to the same value they were.

Comment: Are you trying to do an insert, or an update? This just looks like you will insert all the existing rows in `ORDERLINES` back into `ORDERLINES` but with a different value (leaving you with two sets of data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update OrderLines
set Calculated = ORDQTY * PRICE - RECQTY
```

or better yet, make this *actually* a computed column that will always be up to date.

```
alter table OrderLines
add Calculated as ORDQTY * PRICE - RECQTY
```

Comment: Thanks! I hate it when I have those dumb guy moments when I get an idea in my head, and follow it down the wrong rabbit hole! This is exactly what I was wanting to do. I don't know why I was stuck on insert rather than update. I think I'm tired.